# What effect does room temp have on the cider fermentation process?

Tags: fermentation, cider, temperature

I'm new to the site. Been making cider for a couple of years now and still don't feel like I have it down. My latest batch, a recipe I've made many times, is not clearing like it usually does. It got quite warm after I started it, so my question is what effect does external room temp have on the fermentation process?

Answer (score 3):

Usually a warm fermentation 72°F+ will generate more yeast esters and fusel alcohols.

The warmer temp makes for rapid yeast growth phase and easy feeding phase. This added growth could be your clairity issue, just having more unfloculated yeast in suspension.

Fusels will mellow with aging 4-8 weeks. Clairity should improve over time 1-3 months, or use a clairifier to accelerate it (gelitan can do it in a couple days). Esters mellow and blend with long 2-24 months aging.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  It's been aging now for 6-8 weeks.  Not showing much improvement in clarity.  And wouldn't ya know it - this batch is for a party.  I've never used gelatin to clear.  What kind of gelatin and how much do I use for a 5 gal batch, etc?

Comment: @cidergirl if the aging of several weeks didn't clear it, gelitan won't clear it much more. Unless you can see a layering of clear and cloudy cider now.

Comment: Yea, actually there's a layer of clear with cloudy below.  Cloudy layer quite a bit larger than clear unfortunately

Comment: @cidergirl ok, get the cider cold 35°. Mix 1/2 tsp Knox unflavored gelitan into 160° distilled water, once disolved add to the cider and swirl it. You should have cider as clear as your top later in a couple days.

Comment: Awesome.  Will do!  Think I'm gonna rack it one more time too just to get any residual sludge from the bottom of the carboy.  Thanks for all the advice.  I just don't understand why this batch was so different that all my other ones!  RRgg!

Comment: @cidergirl this Apple juice may have been heat pasteurized.

Comment: It's a peach/ginger.  No ginger yet, just the peach/apple blend, w Trader Joe's juices.  But this will work!